# jQuery TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: jquery

I have this `ajax` function which send an array parameter and save it to db. It works fine cause it has been invoked many times in our project.

This is the snap of the function:

```
function InsertProjectList(projectList, pageUrl, remark) {
    if (projectList.length === 0) return;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/StatsService.asmx/InsertListToProjectStats",
        data: "{ 'projectList': " + JSON.stringify(projectList) + ", 'pageUrl': '" + encodeURI(pageUrl) + "', 'remark': '" + escape(remark) + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () { },
        complete: function () { },
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
        }
    });
}
```

But then I'm getting this `projectlist` by following jquery operation and it does return an array like `["195", "254", "784"]` which I expected but my `ajax is unable` to send list parameter in this case. I want to know what's wrong here? The browser console showed `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.`

```
var projectList = $("ul#plist .project-list").filter(':onScreen').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("projectid");
});

InsertProjectList(projectList, $(location).attr("href"), remarkText[4]);
```

I know I could use `jQuery each` function to get this array of `projectId` but this is not my intent.

Comment: No sure, try with `data: JSON.stringify({projectList:projectList, pageUrl: encodeURI(pageUrl), remark: escape(remark) }),`

Comment: Why the hell data is a string and not an object?? Why do you do such a cruel thing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are returning from the jQuery `.map()` function. It doesn't return a javascript array, it returns a jquery object which having an array. So `JSON.stringify` over that object won't work thus you are having a `TypeError`.

```
var projectList = $("ul#plist .project-list").filter(':onScreen').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("projectid");
}).get();
```

`.get()` will convert your `.map()` object to javascript array then you will be able to `JSON.stringify()` over this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes on your `data` field, and try to pass the object without stringifying it.

And I don't think you can stringify an Array (it looks like an array, doesn't it ?)

```
function InsertProjectList(projectList, pageUrl, remark) {
    if (projectList.length === 0) return;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/StatsService.asmx/InsertListToProjectStats",
        data: { projectList: JSON.stringify(projectList)
              , pageUrl : encodeURI(pageUrl)
              , remark: escape(remark)
              },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () { },
        complete: function () { },
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
        }
    });
}
```

In this case, you should be able to pass the object (as an array) trought the ajax request.

Comment: I can't do it. `InsertProjectList` function has been invoked numerous times in our projects. I can't refactor this code right now. Though if nothing works I will create a new function for this. Thanks.

Comment: We can do it, I am sure. Can you specify the type of data this function attempt to receive . Ex.: an array [field1:value1, field2:array[value2, value3], ... this would help.

Comment: And I confirm you don't need to stringify the `data` field, you can pass an object.

Comment: I am expected to send a simple array like ["2417","2418","2419"]. What I meant before is I can't change the code from JSON.stringify(projectIdList) to something else. Its been used and tested in many pages. Beside its not my call to change it. :(
Can't I do something to the caller function?

Comment: Ok. I am not sure this is really madatory, but OK. First of all, let the `data` field be an object. I updated my code. Try this and also tell me if the page is loaded or if it fails before posting.

Comment: I tried with your updated code. Still getting error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Comment: Is the request posted or not ? Did you try without `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: You can also try not to specify the `dataType` and `contentType`. And do a `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function, just to see exactly the response of the page (I think it is the received data that the browser cannot parse into JSON)